# Saving Imshow() Output - Scaled images saving to disk

Tags: file-io, fft, matlab

I've started learning about image processing in Matlab and I have a small problem.

I'm trying to visualize FFT of images. The function imshow does what I need, when I supply the empty matrix (e.g. sintax imshow(image, [] ).

Now, the imshow does a good job because when supplied with the empty matrix, it will display the lowest value in the picture as black, the highest as white and will adjust all the other values accordingly. (at least that is how I understood it).

The scaling that imshow does is great and I was wondering if there is a Matlab function that would take an image and perform that kind of scaling? I thought of saving the pictures manually after using imshow, but I would like to do this programatically.

I assume there is a nice Matlab feature that does this, but after googling around, I couldn't find any solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to rescale your image so that its minimum is zero, and its maximum is 255 (for 8-bit image) before calling `imwrite`.

For example:

```
img = randn(100);
figure,imshow(img,[]); %# show the image

mx = max(img(:));
mn = min(img(:));

imgScaled = (img-mn)/(mx-mn);

%# convert to uint8 and save
imwrite( uint8(round(imgScaled*255))), 'test.tif');

%# reload and display without scaling 
%# if we have done everything correctly
%# the images before and after should look alike
imgLoaded = imread('test.tif');
figure,imshow(imgLoaded)
```

Comment: I was hoping there was a Matlab build in solution, but this works out nicely and is exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `imagesc` is what you want, [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imagesc.html).  But naturally to display a FFT you'll have to get rid of the complex values, e.g. do something like create magnitude, phase plots separately.  But this said, `imshow` already is a Matlab function that does scaling so I'm not quite sure why you need a new function; `imagesc` lets you get color, at least.

Then for saving, use `imwrite`.

Comment: What imshow does is great for me. But, saving the image is my problem, since if I just use imwrite, it'll save the image as it is, without the scalings that imshow offers. p.s. I use the magnitude of the FFT to visualize if it matters.

Basically, what I want is to save the output of imshow, but to do so from Matlab code, rather than having to click on 'Save as...' etc, since I've got a number of pictures to save.

Comment: @MrMatlabUser I see.  So then as Jonas points out, you can just scale the image data yourself in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of good answers to this, but for a quick hack you might want to `print` what you see in the figure, just see `doc print` for more info.